# Filtering on tableView Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I have `listWidget` contains string list. I can filter it properly using this code:

```
void MainWindow::on_txtFilter_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QRegExp regExp(arg1, Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget->addItems(picNameList.filter(regExp));
}
```

Now, I created a `tableView` in order to add icons next to those strings. I created a `QStandardItemModel` for filtering but I don't know how to do that. Any help?

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_search_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QRegExp regExp(arg1, Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::Wildcard);
    QStandardItemModel* model= new QStandardItemModel();
    model->clear();   
}
```

Comment: what is `picNameList`?

Comment: RTFM? : [Custom Sort/Filter Model Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html)

Comment: @eyllanesc the list contains strings

Comment: @user302686, you need to create a `QStandardItem` for each item in the `picNameList` and add each to the model.